# new windows cannot find path in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I m facing problem with javascript new window.
when i run start.aspx file which is in temp folder.
temp folder has also download.aspx file. When I click a download button then I write a javacript code. The code is

```
new win = window.open("download.aspx", "new window", param);
```

download.aspx file exist in same folder where start.aspx exist.

following error is return

```
 "'win' is null or not an object".
```

Note: This error return after deploy the file. On local it is running fine.

Is there any body help me whats the problem is here??

Comment: why you have written new before win

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use `new` here.

Change

```
new win = window.open("download.aspx", "new window", param);
```

To

```
var win = window.open("download.aspx", "new window", param);
```

Comment: Can you your relative path in here like if your page is in temp and temp is no root then try "/temp/download.aspx"

Comment: i don't think so that relative path like "/temp/download.aspx" will work in javascript. Is it work?

Answer (score 0):

@Farrukh Shahid

should it really have to be relative? Have you tried using full url?

```
var win = window.open('http://your-server-address/download.aspx', 'new window', param);
```